# Visualize time series in a plot

Tags: r

I installed a package from https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/time-series-data-in-r/
using

```
install.packages("fma")
```

Now I want to select one data set which contains monthly time series, for example "boston" and visualize the time series in a plot.

However I am stuck as I don't know do I do that with the lubridate package or something else? I would appreciate some help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `plot(boston)` like this:

```
install.packages("fma")
library(fma)  
plot(boston)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am trying  to add to this plot two smoothed curves in different color by using local polynomial regression fitting. I thought I can do that by using  the command loess(), I also want to select a small respectively bigger value for the parameter span. However, it's not working really. I can't apply loess(). I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JeffAnderson, I would suggest asking that as a different question. That is a different specific problem that can be solved by asking a different reproducible question.